# forgot opengl32.lib xD

Tags: opengl, glew, sdl-2

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClear@4 referenced in function "void __cdecl render(void)" (?render@@YAXXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glClearColor@16 referenced in function "bool __cdecl initGL(void)" (?initGL@@YA_NXZ)
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glDrawElements@16 referenced in function "void __cdecl render(void)" (?render@@YAXXZ)
```

Trying to compile the "modern opengl" example for SDL2 at http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/.
My VS2012 project platform is set to win32 and I pointed the lib directories to the 32bit directories of SDL2.1.15 and Glew1.10. But something is amiss?

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <gl\glew.h>
#include <SDL_opengl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
```

linking:
glew32.lib
glew32mx.lib
SDL2.lib
SDL2main.lib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has *absolutely nothing* to do with GLEW. Those unresolved external symbols come from `opengl32.lib`, which you unfortunately forgot to include in your linking libs.

What is more, you should not be using `glew32` and `glew32mx`; you cannot write software that is ***both*** single-context **and** multi-context. It is either one or the other.

Chances are pretty good you are doing single-context management, you would know and understand why you need `glew32mx` if you had a legitimate use-case for it.

Comment: Oh, silly me. I got lost in a sea of version changes and poor documentation. I'll change my post title.